# multi threaded webRequest issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpwebrequest

I am having some difficulties with multi threaded webrequests, I want to perform 100 GET requests on a url in once by using the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RUN TASK: " + i);
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                makeRequest();
            });
        }
        Console.Read();

    }
    public static void makeRequest()
    {
        string html = string.Empty;
        string url = @"https://192.168.205.50/api/v1/status";
        Console.WriteLine("GET ON:" + url);

        ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = true;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1000;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got response");
            html = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

The url has a sleep of 30 seconds in it the result: the code does only open a url every 1 second instead of 100 at once.

Comment: Are you getting the "GET ON" messages all at once or once every second?

Answer (score 1):

Personally when I have to do a significant number of HTTP requests, I use async/ await and do something like

```
var stringsToCall = /* list/enumerable of uris */
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); // Don't declare this locally, and only use an instance. Leaving it here for simplicity.
return await Task.WhenAll(urlsToCall.Select(url => client.GetAsync(url)));
```

This will create a series of tasks to our HTTP calls and allow us send out many at once.
If you're interested, read into async/await.